# javax.naming.NoPermissionException: User <anonymous> does not have permission on jndi.dataSource to perform lookup operation

Tags: java, weblogic, datasource, jndi, weblogic12c

I've recently added security restrictions to the JNDI lookup of a data source on a Weblogic instance - a role encapsulating some groups and a system user to be used by the background processes in the application.

The server starts correctly, but after some time (about 2 days after the last restart) it starts throwing this error and the data sources become inaccessible:

> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is **javax.naming.NoPermissionException: User `<anonymous>` does not have permission on jndi.dataSource to perform lookup operation.**

To that extent, I've also added the security restrictions on the data source itself and created the user in the security realm used by the application and made some application-side changes:

- in the `weblogic descriptor file`, I've added the following lines, so as to run the application by default with the aforementioned system user:

  ```
  <wls:run-as-role-assignment>
      <wls:role-name>systemUser</wls:role-name>
      <wls:run-as-principal-name>systemUser</wls:run-as-principal-name>
  </wls:run-as-role-assignment>
  ```
- added this `security-role` to the web.xml:

  ```
  <security-role>
      <role-name>systemUser</role-name>
  </security-role>
  ```
- and specified this in the `servlet` definition, also in web.xml:

  ```
  <run-as>
      <role-name>systemUser</role-name>
  </run-as>
  ```
- use a jndiTemplate configured with the system user to access the JNDI resource:

  ```
  <bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
      <property name="environment">
          <props>
              <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory</prop>
              <prop key="java.naming.security.principal">systemUser</prop>
              <prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">systemUserPassword</prop>
          </props>
      </property>
  </bean>
  ```

Weblogic version: **12.1.3.0.7**

Java version: **jdk1.8.0_91_unlimited**

Did anyone encounter this behavior before? Why is complaining about a virtual user(anonymous) on some Weblogic instances and admin on others? How could I mitigate this?

Comment: Verify if "Anonymous Admin Lookup Enabled" on Domain/Security/General

Comment: It wasn't. I've made the change and the issue has yet to appear until now.

Comment: Has it passed the usual error recur period ?

Comment: Not yet. It is difficult to track, because it happens unpredictably - it happened 3 days after the last restart once (the earliest) and 7 days after the last server restart (the latest). Still keeping it under surveillance for 2-3 days and if it doesn't occur again, that must have been the correct fix.

Comment: I see , makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I had a similar problem before. Here is how I lookup secured jndis.

```
<bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
    <property name="environment">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.security.principal">systemUser</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">systemUserPassword</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate"></property>
    <property name="jndiName" value="myJndiName"></property>
    <property name="exposeAccessContext" value="true"></property>

</bean>
```